# Natural set construction with Elementary Theory of the Category of Sets

Tags: group-theory, definition

I'm learning type theory by myself, so first I'm trying to understand the differences between ZFC and ETCS. I'm familiar with ZFC, it is how I reason about sets, but I'm having trouble trying to see things through the ETCS. I stumbled across the definition of the natural set. ZFC looks very straight-forward but ETCS looks like I'm missing something. The definition I found is $\Bbb{N}$ as having an element 0 and a function 
$$
s: \Bbb{N}  →\Bbb{N}
$$
 It is trivial that $s$ has closure, but it means nothing else to me. How exactly $s$ relates to 0? Is that definition loose and lacking things or I'm just missing the point of Elementary Theory of the Category of Sets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're missing is the universal property: that $1 \xrightarrow{0} \mathbb{N} \xrightarrow{s} \mathbb{N}$ is *initial* among such diagrams. Given any other diagram

$$ 1 \xrightarrow{a} X \xrightarrow{r} X $$

there is a *unique* map $f : \mathbb{N} \to X$ such that $f0 = a$ and $fs = rf$.

That this map exists and is unique is basically the principle of recursive definition, where $a$ is the initial value and $r$ is the recursive step. For example, you can see that this implies the iterates

$$ f0 = a \qquad fs0 = ra \qquad fss0 = rra \qquad fsss0 = rrra $$